# Powershell Form - ListView - Populate Columns

Tags: wpf, powershell, listview

I have designed a Powershell Gui Tool, the tool is designed works pretty well but I am stuck on how to populate the listview columns with the data from several xml files.

I have four column that I want populate

```
# ListView
$LvMain= New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Listview
$LvMain.Location = '300, 55'
$LvMain.Name = "ListViewInfo"
$LvMain.Size = "850, 600"
$LvMain.Text = "Pattern text"
$LvMain.Scrollable = $true 
$LvMain.ContextMenuStrip = $ContextMenu
$LvMain.FullRowSelect = $True
$LvMain.GridLines = $True
$LvMain.UseCompatibleStateImageBehavior = $False
$LvMain.View = "Details"
$LvMain.font ="lucida console"
$LvMain.Controls.Add($ApplicationFormListViewInfo)
# Columns
$LvMain.Columns.Add("FileName")
$LvMain.Columns.Add("Folder")
$LvMain.Columns.Add("Line")
$LvMain.Columns.Add("Path")
```

It is meant when i hit the button " Run "
I will draw out the data from several xml files with

```
$GetXmlData = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Recurse -force -Include $FileTypes | Select-String -Pattern $Pattern
```

And populate the columns with the `$Patterns Filename,Foldername,Line ( which line the pattern is ) and Path ( UncPath ).`

However, a realy good tutorial on how listview works is hard to find.

Anyone who knows how to guide me to the right way ?

Comment: You need to create collection of ListViewItem with subitem for any column.

Comment: thanks for the advice @fdafadf, it made my head actually lite more clear about it